# How do I link folders to domains/subdomains in AWS?

Tags: apache, amazon-web-services, amazon-route53

In AWS Amazon Linux AMI there seem to be subfolders of /var/www/ that are linked to domains and subdomains...

e.g. var/www/folder1 linked to test.domain.com and var/www/folder2 to something.domain.com and var/www/folder3 to domain2.com

In Route 53 it only seems to say the IP address of the server (which is always the same) and the path doesn't seem to be specified.

The guy who set it up has gone and I need to know how to do it for other domains and subdomains.

Comment: Can you phrase this as a question so we know what you're trying to answer?

Comment: It sounds like it's using an [Apache VirtualHost setting](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/examples.html).

Comment: Is your web server Apache or Nginx or something else?

Comment: It's Apache. BTW I'm not at work at the moment. BTW this looks good too: http://calebogden.com/multiple-websites-amazon-ec2-linux-virtual-hosts/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the VirtualHost file in /etc/httpd/conf.d/virtualhost.conf